# How much to read from socket when using select

Tags: sockets

I'm using `select()` to listen for data on multiple sockets. When I'm notified that there is data available, how much should I `read()`?

- I could loop over `read()` until there is no more data, process the data, and then return back to the select-loop. However, I can imagine that the socket recieves so much data so fast that it temporarily 'starves' the other sockets. Especially since I am thinking of using select also for inter-thread communication (message-passing style), I'd like to keep latency low. Is this an issue in reality?
- The alternative would be to always read a fixed size of bytes, and then return to the loop. The downside here would be added overhead when there is more data available than fits into my buffer.

What's the best practice here?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this is implemented on other platforms, but on Windows the `ioctlsocket(FIONREAD)` call tells you how many bytes can be read by a single call to `recv()`. More bytes could be in the socket's queue by the time you actually call `recv()`. The next call to `select()` will report the socket is still readable, though.

Answer (score 0):

The too-common approach here is to read everything that's pending on a given socket, especially if one moves to platform-specific advanced polling APIs like [`kqueue(2)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kqueue&apropos=0&sektion=0&format=html) and [`epoll(7)`](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/epoll.7.html) enabling *edge-triggered* events. But, you certainly don't have to! Flip a bit associated with that socket somewhere once you think you got *enough* data (but not everything), and do more `recv(2)`'s later, say at the very end of the file-descriptor checking loop, without calling `select(2)` again.

Then the question is too general. What are your goals? Low latency? Hight throughput? Scalability? There's no single answer to everything (well, except for 42 :)